# dynamically add html and data from database (using LINQ)

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to achieve something like this:
See Image [Here](http://tinypic.com/r/29kvyg4/8)

where the list of categories (and list of their respective objectives are extracted from a database using LINQ)

I tried following in codebehind:

```
DataClassesDataContext dc = new DataClassesDataContext();

var divcount = (from cnt in dc.dml_np_Categories
                select cnt).Count();

int dv = Convert.ToInt32(divcount);

for (int i = 0; i < dv; i++)
{
    DataClassesDataContext tb = new DataClassesDataContext();
    var ctitle = (from cat in tb.dml_np_Categories
                  where cat.Pk_Category_Id == (i+1)
                  select cat.Category_Title);

    HtmlGenericControl adddiv = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
    adddiv.Attributes.Add("class", "category");
    HtmlGenericControl addh3 = new HtmlGenericControl("h3");
    addh3.Attributes.Add("class", "h3");
    addh3.InnerText = ctitle.ToString();

    catblock.Controls.Add(adddiv);
    adddiv.Controls.Add(addh3);}
```

I am getting following output!

See Image [here](http://tinypic.com/r/15mgxoo/8)

I have 3 categories in the database table, but as you can see, instead of category title it's displaying some sql.

Also I have no clue how to proceed further to add objectives under each category as hyperlink list `<li>`.

Need help with the LINQ query for same as well.

I know I have asked alot, but please help me of this. I'm in learning phase. I tried for a complete day on my own but could not get the desired results.

Comment: Any other way of achieving the desired output (as shown in the first image) would also be appreciated!

Comment: I think it would be a lot easier to use a repeater to achieve this, instead of all the code behind

Comment: Why has the question been downvoted??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some issues with your code, I'll try to point them out. Your LINQ-expression is returning a query, that you call .ToString() on which results in the image above. If you call .First on the query it will return the first item int the result. I'm guessing there will only be one result in the query.

```
//Move this outside of the for-loop
DataClassesDataContext tb = new DataClassesDataContext();
for (int i = 0; i < dv; i++)
    {

        var ctitle = (from cat in tb.dml_np_Categories
                      where cat.Pk_Category_Id == (i+1)
                      select cat.Category_Title).First();

        HtmlGenericControl adddiv = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
        adddiv.Attributes.Add("class", "category");
        HtmlGenericControl addh3 = new HtmlGenericControl("h3");
        addh3.Attributes.Add("class", "h3");
        addh3.InnerText = ctitle.ToString();

        catblock.Controls.Add(adddiv);
        adddiv.Controls.Add(addh3);
}
```

Comment: What should be done? If you could open the first link, I want that result.

Comment: Have you added the .ToFirst()-call in the end of the query?

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify current code with one query, instead of two (one to get count of total title, and another to get list of title).

```
DataClassesDataContext dc = new DataClassesDataContext();
var ctitle = (from cat in dc.dml_np_Categories
              select cat.Category_Title);
foreach(string title in ctitle)
{
    HtmlGenericControl adddiv = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
    adddiv.Attributes.Add("class", "category");
    HtmlGenericControl addh3 = new HtmlGenericControl("h3");
    addh3.Attributes.Add("class", "h3");
    addh3.InnerText = title;

    catblock.Controls.Add(adddiv);
    adddiv.Controls.Add(addh3);
}
```

Regarding the other question, about how to display list of objective for each category, better to [open new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Post your latest code that already working to display category title, and how you get list of objective from database. Because that is another problem, and currently we can't tell anything about objectives (no information about it provided in question).

Answer (score 0):

Your ctitle is not of type you want, that's why you've added ToString(). You write this

```
(from cat in tb.dml_np_Categories
                  where cat.Pk_Category_Id == (i+1)
                  select cat.Category_Title).FirstOrDefault();
```

but it is a bad idea to make a bunch of database calls. You should do the only one and then iterate through the result.

Comment: I don't just want the first row. I want all the rows and add them in individual header (if you could open first link and see the image).